# Oracle 11g - factorial not working with large numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, statistics

I'm trying to replicate some formulae form an Excel sheet in Oracle. In the Excel sheet the formula is:

```
LN(FACT(n))
```

However I found that if you get up to n=170 it returns an error because the number is too large. I found that using the following formula got around this problem:

```
GAMMALN(n+1)
```

This seems to return the same result and can handle very large numbers.

I'm trying to replicate this in Oracle, and I'm getting the same problem - when I try to calculate the factorial in PLSQL it falls over if you try working it out for any number of 83. Is there any way of doing this in PLSQL? Either working out the factorial for very large numbers or reproducing the GAMMALN function?

Here's the code I've got for my factorial function, which as mentioned before falls over if you try inputting more than 83:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION FACTORIAL(X IN INTEGER) RETURN NUMBER AS
  FACT_VALUE NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN

  FOR I IN 1..X LOOP
    FACT_VALUE := FACT_VALUE * I;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN FACT_VALUE;
END;
```

Thanks

## UPDATE

Thanks to David Aldridge's suggestion that the log of lots of numbers multiplied together equals the sum of all the logs, I've come up with a PLSQL function which works for large numbers:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION LN_FACTORIAL(X IN INTEGER) RETURN NUMBER AS
  FACT_VALUE NUMBER := 0;
  TMP_VAL NUMBER;
BEGIN

  FOR I IN 1..X LOOP
    TMP_VAL := LN(I);
    FACT_VALUE := FACT_VALUE + TMP_VAL;
  END LOOP;


  RETURN FACT_VALUE;
END;
```

## UPDATE 2

I found that whilst this function works fine, the operation I was doing required this calculation to be done many times on large numbers. Therefore the above approach took a very long time to work it out multiple times. The solution I came to in the end was to use the results of the above function to populate a table with the result for all numbers 0-200,000. Then when I needed the factorial I just query the table, which is a lot faster.

Comment: What error gets raised?

Comment: Well for instance if I do "SELECT FACTORIAL(84) FROM DUAL;" it returns the string "infinity" instead of a number. If I try to do "SELECT LN(FACTORIAL(84)) FROM DUAL;" which is my ultimate goal, I get a "ORA-01426: numeric overflow" error which is because the number is too big.

Comment: WRT your "UPDATE 2": another alternative to consider is to use Oracle's Function Result Cache http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=504

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number will store values up to but not including 1.0 x 10^126

Give it a go with the binary_double data type, which handles up to 1.79769313486231E+308: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#autoId10

Otherwise, I seem to recall that the logarithm of lots of numbers multiplied together is the same as the sum of all of their logarithms -- if so it ought to be an easy code change.

In fact you can do this in pure Oracle SQL, which would be much faster.

```
select sum(ln(rownum)) ln_fact
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

On SQLFiddle it will calculate up to 20,000 in just over a second. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/007bd/58

Comment: Thanks, that now works for numbers up to 170. However, the Excel sheet I'm trying to replicate has numbers up to 8000! Perhaps there's another way of working out LN(FACT(n)) which doesn't involve such huge numbers...

Comment: Yep, looks like you're right! I've included the code for my new (working) function in my question! Thanks!

Comment: Nice on -- added a note on doing this in pure SQL too.